# TABLES DB2 longDescription

Tags: db2

Good afternoon.

Can you help me, I would like to know, how the longDescription table in `IBMDB2` works and how do I bring the result which is inside the columns?

Thank you.

Comment: Which OS? What is your understanding of a longDescription table? Please provide more details to your question

Comment: Do you mean difference between System name and Sql name on IBM i?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the longDescription is one of Maximo Asset Management tables.
If so, here is an example, how to handle it in Db2 on AIX/Linux.

1. logon as the instance owner on the machine, such as db2inst1
2. Run below at command prompt to list up all databases name(s) under the instance:
   **$ db2 list db directory**
3. Then run below to use one of database name(s):
   **$ db2 connect to DBNAME**

   - please replace DBNAME as your target database name, such as sample.
     ie.  db2 connect to sample
4. Then run below to list up all table names in the database DBNAME
   **$ db2 list tables**

   - it will list all table names and its schema name, type and creation time
5. Then run below to list up all columns in the table.
   **$ db2 describe table SCHEMA.TABLENAME**

   - replace SCHEMA like db2inst1 and TABLENAME like longDescription
     ie.  db2 describe table db2inst1.longDescription
   - it will list up all column names and some other information
6. Then run below to get data from a column, such as idownertable.
   **$ db2 select COLOMN_NAME from SCHEMA.TABLENAME**

   - replace  COLOMN_NAME like ldownertable
     ie. db2 select ldownertable from db2inst1.longDescription
7. If we want to see all data in the table, run below:
   **$ db2 select * from SCHEMA.TABLENAME**
       ie. db2 select * from db2inst1.longDescription

Hope this helps.